# KDE Plasma not detecting external display

Tags: arch-linux, kde, nvidia, display, optimus

Whenever I connect to an external display on Arch Linux, it doesn't display anything. While the HDMI cable is plugged into my laptop and I run `xrandr -q`, I get the following output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 210mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.02    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     74.76    59.98  
   1600x900     144.00    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1368x768     144.00    59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720     144.00    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   1024x576     144.00    59.90    59.82  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540      144.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   864x486      144.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405      144.00    59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   640x400       85.08  
   640x360      144.00    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

When I run `glxinfo | egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"` I get

```
egrep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
```

Also, it prompts me to select if I want to switch to the external screen, unify outputs, extend display to the left or extend the display to the right when I plug in the HDMI cable or unplug it. Clicking either of those options in the prompt does nothing.

For context, I am using `linux-zen-6.0.11.zen1-1` and `nvidia-dkms`, and using KDE Plasma as my graphical environment.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by installing the package `linux-zen-headers` which makes `nvidia-dkms` compatible with `linux-zen`.